# Searching documents at scale: how to maintain cleaned documents?

Tags: text-mining, data-cleaning, recommender-system

I have a document-store database (MarkLogic) with hundreds of thousands of news articles in raw format. I am building a content recommender on a representative subset of that data on my local machine. I'm likely going to use Tfidf or Jaccard similarity to recommend documents, but I'm concerned about how I might actually implement whatever recommender algorithm I come up with back into my larger production database, as I will be cleaning raw text data (i.e. removing stopwords, punctuation, stemming, etc.) to build the model (so that, for example, I have one feature representing the word "hello" -- not "Hello", "hello", "hello.", and so on).

**How do large search engines like Google and Yahoo! implement these types of algorithms (i.e. algorithms that were built using cleaned data, but must work for raw, uncleaned data)?** I can't imagine they maintain two schematically-identical databases - one clean and the other unclean - for these types of problems. I also think that, while Google has insane compute power, they are certainly not cleaning every document in their database each time a query comes in.

Comment: Space is cheap; save both. Especially if it's merely text!

Comment: @Emre there must be more to it than that, though. You're telling me Google (assuming they don't do anything else to solve this problem) should roughly *double* the number of data centers they have just to accommodate this configuration?

Comment: How much space do you think all the news articles in the world take? You can always compress the raw text.

Comment: They keep them and you can even see it! Go do a Google Search. Next to a result, click the little green down arrow, and then "Cached". That's their copy.

Comment: @CalZ I'm sure Google is keeping everything. But my question is if this duplication of databases - one raw, one cleaned - is the best approach. I imagine it would be tough explaining to my boss that we need to spin up a new database to accommodate my recommender.

Comment: I was simply continuing the comment conversation but I also left an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this problem as a pipeline of steps to automate and re-run, and not just the ML step at the end:

1. Read in raw documents.
2. Stem words, remove stop words.
3. Perform TF-IDF
4. Train model on cleaned up data.

Now when it comes time to score:

1. Load your saved model.
2. Repeat steps #2 and #3 from above.
3. Send the *cleaned* data into your model for a prediction/recommendation.

Here is an example in Python of something like that:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html